# Как получить уникальные элементы в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как я могу получить уникальные элементы в массиве в js? Я знаю, что есть `new Set`, но если в массиве будут объекты, то он не сработает

Например, этот код выведет это: `[1, 2, { key: "1" }, { key: "1" }, { key: "1" }]`

```
[...new Set([1, 1, 2, { key: "1" }, { key: "1" }, { key: "1" }])];
```

А мне нужен такой результат

```
[1, 2, { key: "1" }]
```

Comment: Ну, объекты по определению уникальны. Так что вам нужно самостоятельно определить функцию «уникальности» которая будет считать такие объекты равными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов решения для вашего массива

```
function getUniqArr(arr) {
  let arrFromSet = Array.from(new Set(arr))

  arrFromSet = arrFromSet.map(el => {
    return typeof el === 'object'
      ?  JSON.stringify(el)
      : el
  })

  const result = Array.from(new Set(arrFromSet))

  return result.map(el => JSON.parse(el))
}
```

Но не подходит если в массиве будут другие массивы
Для решения этой проблемы функцию нужно немного дописать, например добавив рекурсию

**UPD**
Так же нужно учесть что тип массива так же является `'object'`
Чтобы узнать является ли элемент массивом используется `Array.isArray(someArr)`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` применим не во всех случаях.

Comment: @Grundy Насколько я знаю, только если есть методы в объекте, тогда не применим

Comment: Есть очень много типов, которые не сериализуются, либо сериализуются так, что десериализация будет не тривиальной

Answer (score -1):

Решил таким образом:

```
const getUniques = array => {
  const sortArray = [...new Set(array)];
  const checkOtherTypes = arr => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]) === JSON.stringify(arr[j])) {
          return checkOtherTypes(arr.filter((item, index) => index !== j));
        }

        if ([arr[i], arr[j]].every(item => item && typeof item === "object")) {
          const getSortKeys = (obj, result = {}, keyTo) => {
            const res = result;
            const sortObj = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((acc, key) => {
              acc[key] = obj[key];

              return acc;
            }, {});

            res[keyTo] = sortObj;

            if (Object.values(sortObj).some(val => val && typeof val === "object")) {
              for (let key in sortObj) {
                if (sortObj[key] && typeof sortObj[key] === "object") {
                  return getSortKeys(sortObj[key], sortObj, key);
                }
              }
            }

            return res;
          }

          const sortObj1 = getSortKeys(arr[i]);
          const sortObj2 = getSortKeys(arr[j]);

          if (JSON.stringify(sortObj1) === JSON.stringify(sortObj2)) {
            return checkOtherTypes(arr.filter((item, index) => index !== j));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return arr;
  }

  return checkOtherTypes(sortArray);
}

// [{ 1: { 2: { ... }, v: 2, key: 2 } }]
console.log(getUniques([{ 1: { v: 2, key: 2, 2: { z: 4, s: 5 } } }, { 1: { key: 2, v: 2, 2: { s: 5, z: 4 } } }]));
```

Comment: Для примера из вопроса такое решение сработает. Но, что если в объектах будут ещё и вложенные объекты, или в объекте будет больше ключей, но порядок у них будет разный?

Comment: @UModeL, исправил

Comment: @UModeL, еще можно добавить проверку на вложенные массивы

Comment: `JSON.stringify` применим не во всех случаях. Есть очень много типов, которые не сериализуются, либо сериализуются так, что десериализация будет не тривиальной

Comment: @Grundy, я написал такое решение для моего вопроса, я понимаю, что не все типы применимы к JSON.stringify, например, DOM элементы